# What do we need for flash 10 development?

Tags: flash, flashdevelop

I'm looking to do some development in flash 10, specifically for the new file api (reading/writing files on the user's local machine). What do I need to develop for flash 10, just Flash cs4?:

http://tryit.adobe.com/us/cs4/flash/c/?sdid=ETJMX&

or is there some other ide? All I'm really interested in doing is:

1. Make a small swf file which reads a file on the user's machine
2. I will host it in an html file
3. When file read is done, I just want to send its contents as a string to a javascript function for further processing.

Not sure if I can get away with the free adobe air thing for this? I need it to run in a webpage but I don't intend to do any more development outside of the above,

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want a free solution:

Download [Flex SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Downloads), then download [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page)

It's perfect for coding.

As security restriction, every time you want to save a file it pops up the Save As dialog box asking the user where to save it. For loading, on user input, you can call the FileReference.browse(); [You can learn more about this class, here.](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/FileReference.html)

Also, you can use AIR to save the file:
(AIR is flash compiled for desktop, you can't use it for web)

```
import flash.filesystem.*;
import flash.events.Event;

var docsDir:File = File.documentsDirectory;
try{
    docsDir.browseForSave("Save As");
    docsDir.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, saveData);
}catch (error:Error){
    trace("Failed:", error.message);
}
function saveData(event:Event):void {
    var newFile:File = event.target as File;
    var str:String = "Hello.";
    if (!newFile.exists){
        var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
        stream.open(newFile, FileMode.WRITE);
        stream.writeUTFBytes(str);
        stream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, starting with Flash 10 you can read a file from the user's workstation directly, with certain security restrictions, of course.

Comment: I am not sure about this, but I thought we are allowed with Flash 10 to read and write files so long as the user clicks a button and picks a file from their machine. Definitely security risks involved and I wouldn't be surprised if this isn't allowed at all, but I *thought* it is now, not sure.

Comment: I never tried that, but I think it is possible, but you'll need to prompt the user with a Open File... dialog box.

Comment: It's possible, I've used it (both saving and loading) :-) As another security restriction, every time you want to save a file it pops up the Save As dialog box asking the user where to save it. For loading, on user input, you can call the `FileReference.browse()` function: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/FileReference.html#browse()

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have all you need to create Flash 10 SWFs with the Flash CS4 authoring tool, however:

As AaronLS points out, Flash CS4 is not a particularly good code IDE (it is more aimed at designers). As an alternative to Flex Builder, there is an open source Flash IDE, called [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=5669), that is quite good. It still requires CS4 (or some other AS3 compiler, like the Flex SDK, which is free) to compile the code, but you get the benefit of a nicer coding environment.

For such a simple task that only involves code (no design), the Flash authoring environment might be overkill, although it is the simplest way to proceed.

You might also want to check out [Haxe](http://haxe.org/) (a language), which can compile to SWFs directly, or compile to AS3 code. For this simple application, I would suggest using Haxe, since it is free and [easy to use for simple SWFs](http://haxe.org/doc/start/flash) (no mucking about with MXML, etc). However, Haxe is not everyone's cup of tea.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Flex Builder instead which is more of a true IDE and more programmer oriented, where as Flash CS4 is more designer oriented.

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely possible to write and compile SWFs using free tools, you can use the free [Flex SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+3) to compile your code, and an editor of your choice. [Flashdevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page), is an excellent actionscript editor, and integrates nicely with the Flex SDK compiler.

These tools will let you do all you want to do.

If you're a student or unemployed, you can even pick up the [Flash Builder IDE for free](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/free/index.html).